# How can my address column in my orders table reference multiple types of address formats?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design

I'm doing this in SQLite

The problem is my orders table needs to have an address to deliver to but there are many different address formats around the world so I have a table for each different format.

Examples of formats:

1. US and similar address - Place name, street address, apt number, city, state, country, zip code
2. Certain places in Africa - Place name, country, state, neighborhood, landmark, distance from land mark, direction from landmark
3. There are many other valid delivery address formats.

So my ideas are:

1. Add null columns to the orders table that reference each address format use a check restraint to confirm there is at least an address.
2. Have separate tables like order_us_address, order_africa_address
3. Create a table called master_address_id and then reference that in each address format table so that i can just references that master_address_id in the orders table

What is the best practice here? Is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

A single address table should work fine. I assume you want to hold all the individual address fields so just add them to your table. For any individual address record, a lot of these columns will be null but that’s not an issue.

Then add columns for Mailing Address Lines (up to the maximum number of lines there could be in a mailing address). Based on the logic you presumably know for how to construct a mailing address for each country, populate these mailing address lines appropriately.